# Mac OS .app package is ignoring the Info.plist

Tags: macos, bash, dock, info.plist, .app

I've written a simple bash script which I have in turn manually bundled into a .app. All I have is the .app container directory, a Contents sub-folder, a MacOS sub-sub-folder, the bash script executable, and the Info.plist file.

The executable is in the MacOS directory while the Info.plist is in the Contents directory.

The problem I'm having is that I do not want the dock icon to show up when I run the app. Therefore, I wrote the following simple Info.plist. However, the app seems to be ignoring the Info.plist because the dock icon still shows up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```